# Java - Check multiplicity between two class

Tags: java, class, multiplicity

I would know It is possible in java language to write function. How to check the links between each class in java ? 
For example 
School |1 ----- 1..*| Student

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you mean measuring a has-a relation or what? This question is so unclear...

Comment: There are several UML tools that can read Java code and create an UML diagram for you, so yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-to-many relationships in Java is typically implemented as a List property:

```
class School {
    private List <Student> students;
    ...
```

So to know how many students does your school have you call `students.size()`.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understant you correctly. But! if you are looking for a way to create UML diagrams I can recomend you ObjectAId plugin for eclipse. Very easy to install and use.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But i would know if i write function which check the links between each class. For example In my class School i have this checkLink function i execut. I have one message with "School |1 ----- 1..*| Student" I don't know if you understand what i want.